# Priority REST: There are no useful errors

Tags: priority-web-sdk

If the server can not respond, it always sends a status of **500** with the text "***An error has occurred.***"
This is an incorrect behavior, the server should return a 4xx status with descriprion of error.
For example, if we send incorrect type for some filter:

> https://my.domain.com/odata/Priority/tabula.ini/demo/DOCUMENTS_D?$filter=CUSTNAME eq P1122

Server should return error "400 - Bad Request" with message "Invalid filters."

Is this issue are common for whole Priority REST ?
How can we enable correct information for errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Request that contains syntax errors or incorrect entity names or variable types,
may result in a 500 error.

I suggest you add to the web.config file the line

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

in the system.web section. 
Then you may see a more informative error.
In most cases it should help you figure out the reason for the error.